# update react component internal object after property changed

Tags: reactjs

I have a WebGL "viewer" setting in a React component.

I used to rely on `componentWillReceiveProps` to update the state of my WebGL viewer:

```
class Viewer extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    this._webGLRenderer = new AwesomeWebGL();
  }

  public componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.models.length !== nextProps.models.length) {
      // find new model
      const newModel = ...
      this._webGLRenderer.add(newModel);
    }
  }
```

However `componentWillReceiveProps` is being deprecated so I am not sure which is the recommended approach in my situation. Controlled and uncontrolled do not seem a good match.

I could use `shouldComponentUpdate` method but that is bad, also in terms of performance.

I think using `refs` may be appropriate in my situation, exposing a new "add" method:

```
// to be access via ref from parents
public addModelToRenderer(model) {
  this._webGLRenderer.add(model);
}
```

Which would be the recommended approach in my situation?

Answer (score 0):

In React v16.3 and above it will be getDerivedStateFromProps. If you are using React v16.3 then you can try with componentDidUpdate. But you should have proper check, otherwise it will go to infinite loop.

Comment: Will my react component will be re-rendered if I change a property that is not called in the render method? Is it better to use didUpdate than shouldUpdate?

Comment: shouldComponentUpdate is used only to stop the unnecessary re-rendering. Changing property(state) should be done by setState which trigger the re-rendering.